# Passing Eval Through Command Argument in Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, eval

I have a link button that I am trying to pass a parameter through into the `OnClick` event handler. To do this I am using the `CommandArgument` field.

I have this link button within a listview so I am retireving the data using `Eval`, so I want to pass that value into the `CommandArgument` as such:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="BTN_ApproveTicket" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("TicketNum").ToString()%>" OnClick="BTN_ApproveTicket_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am doing this exact think with some table elements in my page, but this one is not working.

The error that I am getting is it is taking the `<%#Eval("TicketNum").ToString()` as a literal, so I am getting a server tag is not well formatted error. Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the `AlternatingItemTemplate` that is in question:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
 <td style="<%#setTicketClass(Eval("TicketNum").ToString(), Eval("UnitID").ToString(), Eval("TicketDate").ToString())%>" >
 <asp:LinkButton id="BTN_ApproveTicket" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TicketNum").ToString()%>'  OnClick="BTN_ApproveTicket_Click">
         <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="<%#setCheckBoxClass(Eval("Approved").ToString())%>" ></i>
         </asp:LinkButton>
         <br />
         <br />
         JobID:
         <asp:Label ID="JobIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobID") %>' />
         <br />
         Ticket #:
         <asp:Label ID="TicketNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TicketNum") %>' />
         <br />
         Unit:
         <asp:Label ID="UnitIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitID") %>' />
         <br />
         Total Ticket Hours:
         <asp:Label ID="TicketHoursLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TicketHours") %>' />
         <br />
          Total Product:
         <asp:Label ID="TicketProductLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TicketProduct") %>' />
         <br />
         Ticket Date:
         <asp:Label ID="TicketDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TicketDate", "{0:MMM dd yyyy}") %>' />
         <br />
         Charge To Customer:
        <asp:Label ID="ChargeToCustomerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChargeToCustomer") %>' />
          <br />
          Received From Customer:
          <asp:Label ID="RecievedToCuLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RecievedToCu") %>' />
          <br />
          Deliver To Customer:
          <asp:Label ID="DeliverTocu" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliverToCu") %>' />
           <br />
           Charged To LSD:
           <asp:Label ID="LBL_ChargedToLSD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChargedToLSD") %>' />
           <br />
           Received From LSD:
           <asp:Label ID="RecievedFromLSDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RecievedFromLSD") %>' />
           <br />
           Delivered To LSD:
           <asp:Label ID="DeliveredToLSDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveredToLSD") %>' />
           <br />
           Subtotal:
           <asp:Label ID="SubtotalLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subtotal", "{0:C}") %>' Font-Bold="True" />
           <br />
           GST:
           <asp:Label ID="GSTLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GST", "{0:P}") %>' Font-Bold="True" />
          <br />
          Total:
          <asp:Label ID="TotalLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total", "{0:C}") %>' Font-Bold="True" />
          <br />
          Job Notes:
          <asp:Label ID="PreJobNotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PreJobNotes") %>' />
          <br />
          Job Description:
          <asp:Label ID="JobDescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobDesc") %>' />
          <br />
          Time Created:
          <asp:Label ID="TimeCreatedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TimeCreated", "{0: MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm}") %>' />
           <br />
          Created By:
          <asp:Label ID="CreatedByLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedBy") %>' />
          <br />
          <asp:LinkButton class="btn-inverse" id="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Enabled='<%# checkButtonEnabled() %>' style="padding: 2px 8px; text-decoration: none; border: solid 1px;" >
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton class="btn-inverse" id="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" onclientclick="return DeleteItem()" Enabled='<%# checkButtonEnabled() %>' style="padding: 2px 8px; text-decoration: none; border: solid 1px;" >
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton class="btn-inverse" id="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Show Product" style="padding: 2px 8px; text-decoration: none; border: solid 1px; white-space: nowrap;" >
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> Show Product
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have to do with quotes - you are using double quotes everywhere, which may confuse parser. Try replacing outer ones with single quote:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TicketNum").ToString()%>'
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but still no luck. Same with reversing and using single on the inside.

Comment: Really strange. Can you post the whole list item template?

Comment: A simple restart of Visual Studio fixed the problem. Although the intelli-sense does not like it, it will run without issue.

Comment: @ChaseErnst, crazy stuff. However I would recommend to stick to outer single quotes in such cases anyway, as it can cause trouble